# JavaScript alert recognizing as same line and showing alert

Tags: javascript, html

[image]In website, I made this. When I press enter, it recognize as new barcode in textarea.
In JavaScript, I made **inserted digits are no more than 6 and Shows alert if more than 6 digits**. But in progress; If I hit enter, there will be new barcode (example, 111111 and 222222 (in next line)) but JavaScript alert is recognized as more than 6 and keeps showing alert. But If I only insert 1 barcode, it works well. My opinion is that JS didn't know for the second inserted barcodes. May I know How can I fix?

```
    $barcode_name = "Seal Number:";
            $barname = "placeholder=\"Enter 6 digits Serial Number.\"";

<br>
      <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="seal_qty">Seal Quantity:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p class="form-control-static" style="margin-top: -6px;">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="seal_qty" name="seal_qty" min="1" placeholder="Enter Seal Quantity" value="<?php echo $seal_qty; ?>">
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10"></div>

<br>
      <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="barcodeno"><?php echo $barcode_name; ?></label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p class="form-control-static" style="margin-top: -6px;">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="barcodeno" name="barcodeno" onkeydown="return KeyDown()" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"<?php echo $barname; ?>></textarea>
            
        </p>
      </div>
      <br>
```

Below is Javascript.

```
var barcodeno = document.translot.barcodeno.value;
      if (barcodeno == ""){
          alert("Please Insert Serial Numbers.")
          return false;
      }
      
      else if (barcodeno.length != 6 ){
          alert("Barcode Numbers must be at lest 6 digits.")
          return false;
      }
      
  

  $('#filter').html(''); // to clear selection
  // lotid = $('#lotid').val().split('\n');
  var barcodeno = $('#barcodeno').val().trim();
  barcodeno = barcodeno.split('\n');
//checking duplicate barcodeno
    let barcodeno_array = []
    for(let i = 0;i < barcodeno.length; i++){
        if(barcodeno_array.indexOf(barcodeno[i]) == -1){
            barcodeno_array.push(barcodeno[i])
        }
    }
    
  var Barcode = barcodeno_array.length;
  //alert (Barcode+'||'+seal_qty);
  if (seal_qty != Barcode){
      alert ("Seal Quantity and Number of BarcodeID must be the same.");
      return false;
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to change this 'barcodeno.length < 6' to this 'barcodeno.length > 6'.  You want to check if there are more than 6 characters, not less.

Comment: @CharlesEF  I've tried adding >6 with || . But If I add >6 and hit enter and write new Barcodes Number in text area, JS still count as the same with the first line and still showing that alert.

Comment: What do you mean 'adding >6 with || '?  Did you also add an OR?  If you did, what was it?  Since I don't use barcode maybe I've mis-understood the question.

Comment: I mean, I've tried else if (barcodeno.length < 6 || barcodeno.length > 6){
    alert("Barcode Numbers must be at lest 6 digits.")
    return false;
   }

Comment: @CharlesEF Barcode is just a name I mean, numbers that i enter is no more than 6 digits or less than 6 digits. Current problem is "If I hit enter and continue writing another 6 digit numbers, it still count as > 6 and showing the alert."

Comment: Have you tried 'barcodeno.length != 6' by itself?  Also, I think browser textareas use '\n\r' or '\r\n', don't remember, as the newline.

Comment: @CharlesEF Yes, I've tried. I just added the screenshot of the error. U can see either I put same 6 digit numbers in two role, still getting the Alert.

Comment: I edited my comment above.  Check how you split the textarea.  I think you should use '\n\r' or '\r\n' as the newline.

Comment: @CharlesEF I use ('\n') to split. I think error is in while checking condition for second line .

Comment: If you're checking for barcode length != 6 on *every keystroke* then you're going to get an error on every keystroke except the 6th one. Please describe the *exact* intended behavior, and maybe rethink your logic. Also, if the JS in your question is the body of the `KeyDown()` function, you'll want to return *true* if `barcodeno.length < 6`, so that the keystroke gets inserted into the textarea.

Comment: @scott, as per the code you are checking for ```<6``` but as per your question, you are getting error that the barcode is longer than 6. If it is latter then , you need to split the barcode by new line and check length for individual line rather than the whole textarea string.

Comment: @gvmani Sorry, I'm checking with both < and > 6 for this. May I know how can I split and check for the second line?

Comment: @scott ``` var barcodeno = $('#barcodeno').val().trim();   barcodeno = barcodeno.split('\n');````You already have the code to split into lines, iterate through the array and do the validation.

Comment: Yes, I've split the numbers each but I don't know how to check second line numbers are inserted <6 or >6 . @gvmani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var barcodenoStr = $('#barcodeno').val().trim();
let barcodes = barcodeStr.split("\n");
let allBarcodeValid = true;
let barcodeno_array = []
for(let i =0; i < barcodes.length; i++){
  let barcodeno = barcodes[i];
  if (barcodeno == "" || barcodeno.length != 6){
    allBarcodeValid = false;
    break;
  }
  //checking duplicate barcodeno
  if(barcodeno_array.indexOf(barcodes[i]) == -1){
    barcodeno_array.push(barcodes[i])
  }
}
if (!allBarcodeValid){
    alert("Entered barcodes are not valid");
    return false;
}
      
      
$('#filter').html(''); // to clear selection

  
//  seal_qty variable is missing

if (seal_qty != barcodeno_array.length;){
  alert ("Seal Quantity and Number of BarcodeID must be the same.");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: To replace, Should I remove my current JS alert checking?

Comment: yes, replace the initial check with the above code.

Comment: So, I have to remove my else if alert and May I know under which line I should paste? This is my first time trying JS so I'm quite confused.

Comment: Also, may I know if (!allBarcodeValid) or if (!=allBarcodeValid)

Comment: Updated the code, you can replace the script portion which you posted. ```seal_qty``` variable is missing in the posted script.

Comment: !allBarcodeValid is the valid check for allBarcodeValid is not true.